# please help undelete this question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

Please help undeleting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api/2252986). This question is highly relevant to API and programming. This post has over 126 upvotes which would mean that there are other people who are thinking the same thing. 
Another user has commented saying: "I don't think this should've been closed. It's potentially very relevant to a lot of web programming tasks." This comment was able to get support from other users and was able to get over 70 upvotes.

Comment: No. We explained to you already how the post was a tire fire of spam, including the links to your service. Let’s just say you are not unbiased here and not talk about that little voting ring. That post will stay deleted.

Comment: I’ll just point you to [Brad’s words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307784/request-to-undelete-this-question#comment1001561_307784) on this as well.

Comment: The only set of users I know of that are interested in bulk WHOIS queries are spammers, Such questions should not be alowed to exist on SO, irrepective of other problems;(

Comment: I won't even bother to respond, I wish I had control over 126 upvotes, enjoy your little bubble in this fantasy world, it doesn't even matter to me.

Comment: @ Martin James: whois data is critical to cyber-security solutions including anti-spam, if you know anything about it.

Answer (score 17):

To provide an answer to this so we can close it out: **no.**

The deleted question was

> Are there any providers of WHOIS APIs?

which is clearly an offsite resource request and off-topic for Stack Overflow. It was closed six years ago and finally deleted once we realized it was a spam magnet. 13 out of the 15 answers there were deleted as spam or non-answers. No such comment as the one you described ever existed on that question or any of its answers.

I deleted the highest-voted answer as the result of an investigation into a massive puppet ring that was boosting spam across the site. More than 30 sock puppet account were used to coordinate votes for answers that promoted whoisxmlapi.com, boosting many of these answers by dozens of votes. Those same accounts posted astroturfing for this site across Stack Overflow. None of the votes on that question or answer can be trusted, so we deleted both.

You appear to be involved with this site, given [your](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47785787/19679) [past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47785627/19679) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47491694/19679). When we deleted this sock puppet ring and the posts they voted for on February 4, 19, and 20, [you appear to have lost quite a bit of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121196/user121196?tab=reputation).

It's also strange that you edited that question to remove a reference to a competing service. I'm sure this was all just a coincidence.

Comment: The links in "your past answers" either link to a deleted question or have no (visible) answers by user121196. Did they disappear overnight?

Comment: @Gimby - They're deleted answers, which were removed because each promoted the same service without any disclosure.

Comment: Right, the truth is more that I just completely misread the intention behind that sentence :)